# Can I use an adapter to connect a welder to a dryer outlet?

Tags: electrical, wiring

Hi I recently purchased a chicago electric 170A MIG welder. It runs on 240V and it draws 20A (single phase) but it has a 50a plug on it (nema 6-50). My dryer outlet is a four prong 240v 30a outlet (nema 14-30). So, my question is can I use [this adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07M86BTZK)?

[image]

It states in the Amazon product description:

> 14-30P Ground connects 6-50R Ground 14-30P Hots connect 6-50R Hots
> 14-30P Neutral is empty(Open)

Here are [the plugs I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAPf8.jpg).

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post a photo of the welder's nameplate?

Comment: Is [this](https://manuals.harborfreight.com/manuals/68000-68999/68885.pdf) the model number # 61888?

Answer (score 5):

Yes that looks like an appropriate adapter for the job.

It is a metal working convention to put the 6-50 plug on welders, plasma cutters, and the like even when they require nowhere near 50 amps to operate. I guess it's analogous to every kind of small appliance (table lamps, alarm clocks, etc) using a 5-15 plug even though they'll draw nowhere near 15 amps. As the 5-15 socket is just the standard around the house; so also the 6-50 socket is the standard around the metal shop.

Answer (score 3):

These are not legal and cannot obtain a UL listing; therefore reputable home stores won't sell them. They are only offered via shady sales channels like AliExpress, BangGood, eBay or Amazon Marketplace, which is an eBay-like flea market folded into Amazon listings.

Some are cheap Chinese and others are built out of UL-listed parts by handymen in their basement.

Another option for you is simply change the welder cord to NEMA 14-30. Dryer cords are readily available that should suffice.